# Displaying Validation errors for WTForm in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm using flask, WTForms and Bootstrap. I've created a form inside of a modal. The problem I've encountered is related to WTForms validation. On form submit, if there are any errors it re-loads the page but without the modal open (and the errors/form are shown in the modal)

I'd like to find a way to have the modal opened (or not reload the entire page, just the modal) if there are errors in the form. So, if I submit the form and there's an issue, I can see the same form with errors included without having to re-open the modal manually.

I am not using AJAX, as I'm not sure how it will work with flask/WTForms. It's a basic account edit form, and my plan is to have it redirect to a different page when submitted (if there are no errors).

Would it be easier to use AJAX somehow? Or is there a simple way for me to force the modal open if the page re-loads after a submit?

Setting data-backdrop to static is not what I'm looking for.

Form field example contained in modal:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    {{form.first_name(value=s.first_name, class="form-control", id="firstname")}}
    {% for error in form.errors.first_name %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{error}}]</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Can anyone please help out on this as I have the same problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX works fine with `Flask/WTForms`. You can find many plugins for this case. For AJAX login view you should return redirect url in response instead direct redirect and if request was correct redirect with js: `window.location = '/redirect/url'`.

Another way is put some flag in your form and check it on page load to show modal.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out something very similar but I'm having no success :(
Could you please look into my question and help me? I'd appreciate it immensely! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61963633/wtforms-textareafield-datarequired-not-raising-validation-error-in-bootstrap-mod?noredirect=1#comment109599045_61963633