# WTForms TextAreaField DataRequired not raising validation error in Bootstrap modal

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have a very small form in a bootstrap modal including just two fields: a TextAreaField and a Submit button. My TextAreField is **DataRequired**.

On top of that this field uses CKEditor (similar to quillsJS) to make the text area WYSIWYG.

Problem is that the form submits even when no data has been entered, and reloads the parent page.

I would very much like to know how to prevent that form submission and raise the validation error when no data has been entered.

I would like to get WTForm validation and not the browser's (which anyway doesn't work either for this case).

I should also mention, in case it matters, that my modal is a partial file (jinja).

My trigger for the modal is this, living in `perfume-cursor.html`

```
<a href="{{ url_for('perfumes.edit_perfume', perfume_id=perfume._id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-2">Edit</a>
```

And this is my modal (in a partial file `perfume-modals.html`)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="reviewPerfumeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reviewPerfumeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteUserModal">Please Leave a Review</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method=POST action="{{ url_for('reviews.review_perfume', perfume_id=perfume._id) }}" id="form-review">
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.review(class="form-control form-control-md", placeholder="Review", id="description") }}
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-primary") }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `id="description"` is what CKEditor uses to render that text area field as a WYSIWYG editor, btw.

I would really appreciate a lot any help on this!!

Thanks in advance!

Update:

In case it helps this is my form class, although I'm pretty sure the issue is modal related and not WTF related:

```
class AddReviewForm(FlaskForm):
    review = TextAreaField("Review", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Post Review")
```

Comment: Can you add your WTForm class to your question? Also, `method=POST` may need to be `method="POST"`, not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! just added the form class. But I'm quite sure this is related to the modal and I'm quite sure I'll need some jQuery to deal with it.
PS: the POST without quotes is just fine.
I have about 20 other forms and all are fine, just the ones in modals have this issue.

Comment: To be clear: the form works fine: when I fill in the text field I update the database as expected. It's just the modal closing instead of staying open showing a validation error 'Data Required" the issue, when I don't enter any text and press submit.

Comment: It could be a bootstrap thing. I'm using a bunch of forms inside modals (not bootstrap) and not having a problem. One last request, can you give the output of an empty form submission via `print(request.form)`

Comment: There's no print at all when I submit the empty form, which is correct. Please keep in mind the fact that I use CKEditor too. If I don't use it, at least the built in validator from the browser keeps the modal open. I just want WTForms to do that instead. All my other forms work well this way when they are not in a modal.

Comment: I meant, add a print statement to the top of the view function and see what is being posted. It will help identify why DataRequired thinks there's data in the form.

Comment: Exactly that’s what I did. There’s no print meaning there’s nothing printed. Only when there’s content there’s something printed. Again, the problem is the modal closing instead of staying open showing my validation errors. That’s what I need to prevent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214482/discussion-between-ryanh-and-guillermo-brachetta).